# Telerik MVC3 Razor Grid - Partial View returning from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, partial-views, telerik-grid

I have a view with several controls that are used for searching. When a user searches (Ajax.BeginForm) off of these I return the data into a PartialView (Telerik MVC3 Grid) that was generated dynamically.

This all works fine. In the grid are buttons for selecting a row. When I select a row, it posts to my controller, I do some "stuff" etc. When I try to get back to the view all I get is my grid data on a page by itself, it displays like a table with no borders, no other controls etc. My code is below.

My partial grid:

```
@model Highlander.Areas.Highlander.Models.ViewModels.DeliveriesGridViewModel
@using System.Data;

@(Html.Telerik().Grid<System.Data.DataRow>(Model.Data.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>())
.Name("Grid")
.DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add("DeliveryID"))
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Command(commandbutton =>
        {
            commandbutton.Select().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText);
        }).Width(80).Title(ViewBag.Title);
    columns.LoadSettings(Model.Columns as IEnumerable<GridColumnSettings>);
})
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Server().Select("_MarkSystem", "Deliveries"))
.EnableCustomBinding(true)
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
)
```

My Controller:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult _MarkSystem(GridCommand command, int id)
{
    string shipDeliver = DataCache.ShipDeliver;
    DataTable fullTable = DataCache.FullTable;

    // call to function to get the datatable data based on the id
    rHelpers.GetDataTableRow(id, fullTable, shipDeliver);

    // get the data for the grid into the model
    fullTable = DataCache.FullTable;
    model = new DeliveriesGridViewModel();
    model.Data = fullTable;
    model.Columns = rHelpers.NewColumns(DataCache.FullTable);

    return PartialView("_DeliveryGrid", model);

    //if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    //{
    //    return PartialView("_DeliveryGrid", model);
    //}
    //return PartialView("_DeliveryGrid", model);
    //return PartialView("DeliveryManager", model);
}
```

As you can see I have tried various things with no success.

Can anyone give me some direction on this.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As far i understand you are using `dataBinding.Server()` that call a server side binding. Use `.Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)` it will work.

Both kind of bindings (Server and Ajax) needs a editing mode. Put an editing mode and try again.Kindly Response if it does not work for you. Here full code of data binding:

```
  **.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                                        .Select("myAction", "myController")
                                        .Update("myAction",myController")).
  Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))**
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I get the same results. I am not sure I understand the reasoning behind the code you gave me. I am not trying to edit the data. I post the row of data I select, do some calculations with the data in the row, then remove it from the grid.

I just cant get it to return to my view and display the entire page correctly. All it shows is my grid, it looks like a table with no borders.

This is my first MVC3 app so maybe I am just not fully understanding what you are saying.

Thanks for your time and I will look forward to your thoughts.